# ZF2 - How To Translate Zend Form Validation Error Messages?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have the .po and compiled .mo language files for diffrent languages.
But language translation is not working on zend form validation error messages.
I dont want to use extra .php file like fr.php for it.

I got this code from [click here](https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.validator.messages.html)

```
$translator = new Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator();
$translator->addTranslationFile(
    'phpArray'
    'resources/languages/en.php',
    'default',
    'en_US'
);

Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
```

Any solution how to implement it in ZF2.

Comment: If you've got the `.po` and `.mo` translation files, why are you adding a `.php` file? Also you haven't stated what the problem with your codes is?

Comment: I just want to add translation in zend form validation errors which is can not be translated because I am using echo $this->formElementerrors(
                    $form->get('username')); which wraps html tags around error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add your `.po` or `.mo` files instead of the `.php` ones, i.e. like this:

```
$translator = new Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator();
$translator->addTranslationFile(
    'gettext'
    'resources/languages/fr.mo',
    'default',
    'fr_FR'
);
Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
```

And then to translate it, use

```
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get("username"),
                              array('message' => $this->translate("errormessage"))
);
```

I don't know how it is with performance of the translation in ZF2, but in ZF1 using arrays in `.php` files was way faster than any other method.

Comment: Thanks.Can you help me how to change the text on buttons formed by zend form in zf2 ?

Comment: You're welcome. Did you mean *How to translate the text* on the buttons?

Comment: Yes.But i resolved it by having the translator instance in zend form from controller while calling Zend form instance.Is there any way to get ServiceLocator in zend form

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with the last one.

Comment: @Havelock I'm sorry that i have to downvote this answer, but for future references, this shouldn't be the way to go.

Comment: @Arvind Please see my answer for an alternative / cleaner solution.

Answer (score 7):

I do not approve of the selected answer :P

When adding a new translator to your configuration, do **NOT** use the default translator-text-domain. The Syntax is as follows:

```
$translator->addTranslationFile(
    $type,
    $resource,
    $textDomain, //<-- this is the important one
    $lang
);
```

In your example you've added a file to the default-textdomain. This, sadly, brings lots of troubles with it, at it will not always work as expected. Whenever you're adding translation files, add them to your own text-domain!

After that, all you need to do is to assign the `Zend\Form\View\Helper` your text-domain. This is done by the following:

```
// For Labels
$this->formLabel()->setTranslatorTextDomain('your-textdomain');

// For Buttons (input type submit)
$this->formButton()->setTranslatorTextDomain('your-textdomain');

// For Error-Messages
$this->formElementErrors()->setTranslatorTextDomain('your-textdomain');
```

**How to get the ServiceManager into the Form?**

This is pretty easy, too. The simples one is to use `constructor-injection` and inject the `ServiceManager` or `ServiceLocator` into the `__construct()` of your Form. On a Controller-Level this would look something like this:

```
$serviceLocator = $this->getServiceLocator();
$form           = new My\Form($serviceLocator);
```

A more in-depth introduction to Form-Dependencies can be found [on my Blog](http://samminds.com/2013/03/zendformelementselect-and-database-values/), where i illustrate the population of a `Zend\Form\Element\Select`-Element on dependent Database-Connections.

**About the Translator itself**

Another thing to note is: as long as there is a Translator-Service attached to your configuration with the name `translator`, it will automatically be attached to the form as default translator. This is a sample configuration i use within my modules regularly:

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'de_DE',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'phparray',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/lang',
            'pattern'  => '%s.php',
            'text_domain' => __NAMESPACE__,
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: What's the point of a text domain? I see it's something about namespacing... so I guess it's to avoid conflicting with other modules that may be translating the same texts?

Comment: @DominicWatson exactly this. It's basically just a common best practice to namespace everything you got, this includes language ressources.

Comment: The Zend Framework's language directory name can be an issue when you use, for example, `$serviceManager->get('translator')->setLocale('en_US')`. In this case, the `pattern` element can't find the directory if its name is "en", like in ZF 2.2 version. Then, you need to rename it to `en_US` or change the  `pattern` 's value to fit this.