# Internationalization (i18n) of Zend Framework 2 forms

Tags: php, internationalization, zend-framework2

I have a small learning app writen using ZF2 (based on ZF2 user guide: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html) and right now I want to add internationalization to my app and it's almost done but I'm stuck on translating forms. When i wanted to use `$this->translate` in form class i got error saying that method translate does not exists. Is there any good example or tutorial about internationalization in ZF2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will quote the answer i have provided [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782558/zf2-how-to-translate-zend-form-validation-error-messages#answer-15788091). I won't bother to edit the texts too much, so do not bother about some of the sentences, but the essence is important and will help you out a lot.

The first thing to get Form-Translation working is to add files to the `translator`

When adding a new translator to your configuration, do **NOT** use the default translator-text-domain. The Syntax is as follows:

```
$translator->addTranslationFile(
    $type,
    $resource,
    $textDomain, //<-- this is the important one
    $lang
);
```

In your example you've added a file to the default-textdomain. This, sadly, brings lots of troubles with it, at it will not always work as expected. Whenever you're adding translation files, add them to your own text-domain!

After that, all you need to do is to assign the `Zend\Form\View\Helper` your text-domain. This is done by the following:

```
// For Labels
$this->formLabel()->setTranslatorTextDomain('your-textdomain');

// For Buttons (input type submit)
$this->formButton()->setTranslatorTextDomain('your-textdomain');

// For Error-Messages
$this->formElementErrors()->setTranslatorTextDomain('your-textdomain');
```

**About the Translator itself**

Another thing to note is: as long as there is a Translator-Service attached to your configuration with the name `translator`, it will automatically be attached to the form as default translator. This is a sample configuration i use within my modules regularly:

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'de_DE',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'phparray',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/lang',
            'pattern'  => '%s.php',
            'text_domain' => __NAMESPACE__,
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: I have that section in my `Application/config/module.config.php` but using gettext or do I have to put it in config file for every module ?

Comment: The `Application` Module only defines the default strings from the SkeletonApplication. If you have your very own Strings to translate, you have to deliver those translation files with your modules and add the files via the abovementioned configuration.

Comment: Ok, now it work BUT i had to change translator type from **`gettext`** to **`phparray`**

Comment: With the config i provided its an phparray, yes. You can modify it to gettext or others, too ;)

Comment: I had gettext and poedit, as suggested on zf2 tutorial page, wasn't finding those strings to translate and I could not use `translate()`  in forms and `$this->getTranslator()->translate()` as someone suggested before (the post was deleted) wasn't working either. So I think that with `gettext` as translator type it is a bit more complicated to translate forms. Anyway with `phparray` everything works great... Thanks.

Comment: I'm absolutely certain that the problem was of another nature. There's no difference as to what source is used. It's all about the right config parameters ;) But as long as it's working for you now everything is great!